# Get-ChildItem -SilentlyContinue throws AccessDenied

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Code:

```
$cPstFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -File -Force `
    -Recurse -Include "*.pst" -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
```

Exception:

```
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At test.ps1:172 char:22
+         $cPstFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -File -Force `
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Context: PowerShell v4.0/.NET 4.5.2/Windows 7.

How is this even possible? And how can I make `SilentlyContinue` do what it's supposed to do?

It's probably worth mentioning that the script doesn't always fail. It fails on some machines but works just fine on others even though on all of them Windows is deployed using the same image.

Comment: Are you sure that there's no whitespace after ` ? Do you get the same result when putting all the parameters on one line

Comment: There is no whitespace and having all parameters on one line doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = “silentlycontinue”
$Extension = "*pst"
    $TargetFolder = "$env:userprofile"
    Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse
```

Comment: Although, I knew about `$ErrorActionPreference`, I never thought about using this workaround. It works. Many thanks!

Comment: This didn't help.

Comment: While this works on the console, it will not assign Get-Childitem's result to a variable.

Comment: I've tried this and it simply stops the error from displaying. Execution of `Get-ChildItem` does not continue after the exception is encountered which is what I was looking for it to do. @Morty this is why a result is not returned. I think it has something to do with using the `-Recurse` switch, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Remotesigned
```

initially PS does not have permissions to execute scripts on system enviornments, thus setting it as ResmoteSigned and running with admin rights can solve the issue.

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just cover it within a `try {}` block and add a `catch {}` routine for such hard errors.

Oh, what I just saw, the ErrorAction should just be SilentlyContinue, not a "SilentlyContinue" String.

Comment: `SilentlyContinue` and `"SilentlyContinue"` are exactly the same when parsed in an argument context

Comment: @Martin Your answer isn't what I need, sorry. There always will be inaccessible files because that's how Windows handles profiles. But that's fine with me, I want to skip non-terminating errors - hence `SilentlyContinue`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into a terminating error because of some special file or directory.  -erroraction won't help with those.  A try/catch would verify that it's happening.  I've seen it in relation to a windows defender folder.  Maybe you can exclude the folder where it's happening.